# Third law of thermodynamics conundrum with cyclic machines

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]

Consider 3 objects, each with different heat capacities ($C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$) and initial temperatures $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$. Heat engines (HE1 and HE2) are placed between the objects to generate work, which powers a heat pump (HP) to transfer heat from object 2 to object 4. Are the final temperatures of objects 1, 2 and 3 all the same? Or is object 2 colder than objects 1 and 3?

I think the final temperatures of objects 1-3 should be the same, since the heat engines will keep running until there are no temperature differences. HE1 will run until $T_1 = T_2$, and HE2 will run until $T_2=T_3$. By the third law of thermodynamics, we therefore have $T_1=T_3$ at this final stage. I don't think the heat pump should influence this result.

Intuitively, however, it seems like object 2 should be colder in the final stage, since it is the only one rejecting heat to a heat pump.

Comment: Have you tried analyzing this problem quantatively (I.e., modeling the problem)?

Comment: @Chester_Miller yes, using $d U = \delta Q + \delta W$ on each system is only useful if I know the final temperature of each system. So I take objects 1 and 2 and realize the heat engine runs until $T_1=T_2$. Well, the same happens with the heat engine between objects 2 and 3. Third law therefore says that $T_1=T_3$. That's really the only analysis I know how to do for this problem. I'm not trying to solve for the final temperature, I just want to determine if the 3rd law applies between objects 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Suppose you assume that the engines and heat pump operate in instantaneous reversible Carnot cycles, based on the current temperatures.  I think you can do something quantitative with that.

Comment: Heat reservoirs are normally considered to be "infinite".  This means that T3>T2>T1 for the "normal" thermodynamic case.  It also means that the three temperatures are constant.

Comment: @David_White, these heat "reservoirs" are actually of finite heat capacity (i.e., normal objects that can change temperature). I made this problem up, so the problem itself may not even make sense or be solvable with the given parameters.

Comment: Questions:  Have you tried a simplified version of this thing where C3 is not present?  Is C4 supposed to be a finite heat capacity body or and infinite heat capacity reservoir?

Answer (score 0):

I describe a similar example [here](http://john.maloney.org/square_root.htm) in the context of three reservoirs, in which the associated heat engine runs one way (and only needs to run one way). The temperatures of two reservoirs are made equal using a reversible heat engine, and then the extracted energy is used to cool down both reservoirs using a heat pump to maximize the temperature of a third reservoir:

[image]
[image]

Your four-component system (for which I'll assume that initially T3 > T2 > T1) introduces an additional factor: can heat engine 1 run in reverse? If not, it's possible that the energy provided by heat engine 2 allows the heat pump to cool T2 below T1. In this case, T2 = T3, which is lower than T1, and T4 is not made as hot as it could be, since a temperature difference still exists among the first three components.

Even if heat engine 1 can operate in reverse (if necessary) but you restrict the order of operation (e.g., heat engine 1 must run before heat engine 2), then you may end up with an inefficient result in which T2 < T1 with no way to exploit this temperature difference.

However, if heat engine 1 can operate in reverse *and* you allow both heat engines to run as long as a temperature difference remains, then all temperature differences can be exploited among T1, T2, and T3 to make T4 as hot as possible. In this case, as you state, T1 = T2 = T3 ultimately.